# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element using TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng, testng-eclipse

Error is thrown when code reaches the line before "almost end".
But error is thrown for the line

```
driver.findElement(By.id("txtEmail")).sendKeys("abc.in");
driver.findElement(By.id("btnEmailSubmit")).click();
```

Please help me in finding out what's causing this exception

Note:Error is shown when I use TestNG

**Code**

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Cookie;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class Otsuka {
  @Test
public void rexulti() throws InterruptedException {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

      driver.get("https://abc/Login.aspx");
        //Setcookie.cookie(driver);
      Cookie name = new Cookie("y1LTtty8PiKwyrj/S5kKv6arXj2KsuVDm5OtdDIUnOQ#","Token=40287A4F0EA6");
        driver.manage().addCookie(name);
        Set<Cookie> cookiesList =  driver.manage().getCookies();
        for(Cookie getcookies :cookiesList) {
            System.out.println(getcookies );

        driver.findElement(By.id("txtEmail")).sendKeys("abc.in");
        driver.findElement(By.id("btnEmailSubmit")).click();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".select2-choice.select2-default>span:nth-child(3)")).click();

        Thread.sleep(4000);

         driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#select2-results-1>li:nth-child(1)>div")).click();

        List<WebElement> allSuggestions = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#select2-results-1>li"));      
      for (WebElement suggestion : allSuggestions)
   {
        if(suggestion.getText().equals("ALASKA AK (OCRGA061A) - HCP")) {
            suggestion.click();
            break;
        }

   }
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".select2-choice.select2-default>span:nth-child(3)")).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);

        List<WebElement> allSuggestionsprovider = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#select2-results-1>li"));      
          for (WebElement suggestionprovider : allSuggestionsprovider)
       {
            if(suggestionprovider.getText().equals("ABRAM, JILL")) {
                suggestionprovider.click();
                break;
            }
        }

    System.out.println("almost end");
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
FAILED: rexulti
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"txtEmail"}
(Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
```

Comment: You are sure there is an element with id "txtEmail" on your page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a very silly mistake that has been made..

```
for(Cookie getcookies :cookiesList) {
            System.out.println(getcookies );
...
...
}
```

You should have ended the for loop after printing the cookie list. Try this

```
for(Cookie getcookies :cookiesList) {
                System.out.println(getcookies );
}
...
..
```